# If $K$ finite field of order $p^8$ where $p\ne3$ then $\sum_{\alpha \in K}{\alpha^2} = 0$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Let $K$ be finite field of order $p^8$ where $p\ne3$ is a prime.

Show that $\sum_{\alpha \in K}{\alpha^2} = 0$.

Comment: What is inside the sum?

Comment: Yes, $\sum_{\alpha\in K}=0$ is meaningless.

Comment: Perhaps it was $\;\sum_{\alpha\in K}\alpha =0\;$ ...? This is at least true, as this sum is the coefficient of $\;x^{p^8-1}\;$ in the polynomial $\;x^{p^8}-1\in\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ .

Comment: Why would the problem exclude $p=3$, then? @Timbuc And it is the coefficient in the polynomial $x^{p^8}-x$, not $x^{p^8}-1$.

Comment: I can't tell, @Thomas. Perhaps the instructor doesn't like number $\;3\;$ ? Or perhaps that's another sum, of course. And yes: the polynomial is $\;x^{p^8}-x\;$

Comment: I don't usually downvote but this time I'm doing it since the OP is unresponsive and that is not nice.

Comment: Sorry for late edit, I couldn't do it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for approach #1: Use the fact in a finite field the non-zero squares form a cyclic subgroup of the multiplicative group, so the sum (well, half of it) is a segment of a geometric series such that...

Hint for approach #2: Let
$$
S=\sum_{\alpha\in K}\alpha^2=\sum_{\alpha\in K^*}\alpha^2.
$$
Because $p^8>3$ (this is enough) there exists an element $\beta\in K^*$ such that $\beta^2\neq1$. Show that
$$
\beta^2S=\sum_{\alpha\in K^*}(\beta\alpha)^2
$$
is actually equal to $S$, because it contains exactly the terms (but in a different order). Conclude that $S=0$.